# Calling Google Visualization API Server-Side

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, flying-saucer

I'm working on a project that involves exporting some HTML reports on a website into PDF format. I'd like to use the excellent [flying-saucer Java library](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject) to do this but my major stumbling block is that several of these reports use the Google Visualization API to generate charts with JavaScript. Flying-saucer doesn't currently support parsing/executing JS, so those charts don't show up in the generated PDF file.

I was hoping to work around this by seeing if there was some kind of web service I could call instead via server-side code that would return the chart image in Base64 as a variable that I could reference in my view instead of getting it via JS.

The old [Google Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) is exactly what I'm looking for, but it has unfortunately been deprecated and it looks like it's slated to be removed completely by next year, so it's not an option.

I'm hoping Google has a newer alternative. If not, is there some other method that's recommended? Thanks!

Comment: Are the charts being rendered client-side at any point before you create the PDF?

Comment: Yes - they're all currently being rendered online via HTML/JS on a website.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `getImageURI` method of the chart to generate an image/octet stream URI.  You can send that data to your server, and you should be able to reconstruct the chart as a .png image file.  I've never tried to do this server-side, so I'm not sure precisely how you would go about it, but this java tutorial might be of some assistance to you: http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-image-to-byte-array-convert-byte-array-to-image/

Comment: That's where I'm getting stuck, unfortunately. If I'm understanding your comment correctly, the user would need to load an individual HTML report in their browser first. For my purposes, I need to provide a link that allows users to generate all of the (many) HTML reports in one PDF file at once. I suppose I could create one page with all the reports on it, and AJAX the URIs to the server, but that seems a bit clunky

This is why I was hoping that Google had some sort of updated web service like the deprecated Image Charts API - it was perfect for getting the stream URI via server-side code.

Comment: There is no replacement from Google (and I strongly doubt there ever will be), but there are other charting APIs, some of which may be able to create images server-side for you.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I wrote [Eastwood Charts](http://www.jfree.org/eastwood/) which implemented the Google Image Charts API as a servlet, backed by [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), so that you could generate charts without having to rely upon Google, or send your data to their servers. :-)

I don't maintain Eastwood Charts anymore (like Google, I can't be relied upon either) but it is open source and the code works so you might find it helpful.  You could also modify it to meet your own requirements, which is something that wasn't possible with the Google service.